# Can I use two types of roads in Valhalla Meili (Map-matching)?

Tags: gis, network-analysis, map-matching

I am currently working with data from scooters which can drive on both bicycle and car lanes/roads. The issue is, when I run map-matching with Valhalla, it is only possible to choose one method and "multimodal" isn't supported.
Is there something I am missing?

There are two things I have considered doing and currently am testing one of those:

1. Alter the OSM data in some way so that bicycle roads would also have "car" attribute or vice versa
2. Perform both map-matchings and later run analysis on choosing the closest of two options

I have tried the second one and although sometimes it is working, it's not always true that the closest would be the best, so topology would have to be considered here somehow..